# Rule that runs code to save attachments turns off

Tags: vba, outlook

This Run a Script code to save attachments stops saving attachments because the rule turns off.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String

sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\andra.aeras\Documents\Test\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    If Right(oAttachment.FileName, 4) = "xlsx" Then
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Is there a way to **"enable"** the rules or improve this code to run properly or run without using rules?

Comment: Please someone help me to understand this code, because after a week the rule that run this scrip in outlook gets error and stop working.

Comment: What is the error you are getting and on what line?

Comment: The rule in outlook start this code to save attachments, like: every email that i receive "with specific text in subject" then "run a script" above.

Comment: there is a way to deal with "enable" the rules? or improve this code to run properly? without rules to activate the script on "thisoutlooksession"

Comment: What does it do *instead* of working?

Comment: @TimWilliams it stops to save attachments because the rule in outlook turns off..

Comment: Are you running the script for all incoming emails?

Comment: Yes i am running for all incoming emails!!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
Sub SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder(OutlookFolderInInbox As String, _
                                 ExtString As String, DestFolder As String)
    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MyDocPath As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim fs As Object

    On Error GoTo ThisMacro_err

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(OutlookFolderInInbox)

    I = 0
    ' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in this folder : " & OutlookFolderInInbox, _
               vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
        Set SubFolder = Nothing
        Set Inbox = Nothing
        Set ns = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create DestFolder if DestFolder = ""
    If DestFolder = "" Then
        Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        MyDocPath = wsh.SpecialFolders.Item("mydocuments")
        DestFolder = MyDocPath & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")
        If Not fs.FolderExists(DestFolder) Then
            fs.CreateFolder DestFolder
        End If
    End If

    If Right(DestFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        DestFolder = DestFolder & "\"
    End If

    ' Check each message for attachments and extensions
    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                FileName = DestFolder & Item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                I = I + 1
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next Item

    ' Show this message when Finished
    If I > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You can find the files here : " _
             & DestFolder, vbInformation, "Finished!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If

    ' Clear memory
ThisMacro_exit:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
    Set wsh = Nothing
    Exit Sub

    ' Error information
ThisMacro_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
         & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder" _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume ThisMacro_exit

End Sub

Sub Test()
'Arg 1 = Folder name of folder inside your Inbox
'Arg 2 = File extension, "" is every file
'Arg 3 = Save folder, "C:\Users\Ron\test" or ""
'        If you use "" it will create a date/time stamped folder for you in your "Documents" folder
'        Note: If you use this "C:\Users\Ron\test" the folder must exist.

    SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder "MyFolder", "xls", ""

End Sub
```

Steps to follow:

1) Go to the VBA editor, Alt -F11

2) Tools>References in the Menu bar

3) Place a Checkmark before Microsoft Outlook ? Object Library
    ? is the Outlook version number

4) Insert>Module

5) Paste the code (two macros) in this module

6) Alt q to close the editor

7) Save the file

Comment: Do i need to create a rule to run this code? or will it run to every message i will receive?

Comment: Did you actually try it to see?  Look at the arguments, and comments, at the end of the script.

Comment: Yes i did, but i didn't understand how to run it, or how it works, i've tried to run manually and went wrong in any case =(. I appreciate your help, but my skills in this kind of vba code is basic...